Strange 80's or 90's Cartoon with strange alien or troll like bad guys flying around in mushroom like ships
There is this animated show that use to play on Saturday mornings, it was definitely not American, but I suspect it was French animation,
It was really bizarre, the hero was this boy with blond or white hair and I think he had some type of gold band on his head.I  think he was bare chested and used magic or had a sword, I'm really not sure, but the whole world was something out of a fantasy.
The only thing I remember clearly were these evil baddies who use to fly around in these strange mushroom like craft that could appear and dissappear, I think smoke also use to come out of these craft and these creatures would plot to harm the boy.I think they were sent by some evil bad guy or women, not sure. 
I'm almost sure the boy had some type of pet with him too, also a strange creature.
I'm almost 100% sure it is a French animation cartoon, defo not American or Japanese.
Anyone who is French or can remember any of these details please HELP!

Thanks everyone, through my persistent mind, I could not give up and kept on digging, and I finally found it, after so many years :)
It was this one, 

 Omer and The Star Child 
Im so happy now, cheers!
